# Need regex to find and replace words from a string

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a string say **"Hello ::2130837661:: stackoverflow, How ::2130837664:: are you?"**

And I have a predefined Integer Arraylist like 
[
    2130837661,
    2130837662,
    2130837663,
    2130837664,
    2130837665,
    2130837666,
    2130837667,
    2130837668
]

I want to check if given string contains integer from that arraylist, it should replace by new word say "EXAMPLE".

For example above string(after replacement) will be :

"Hello EXAMPLE stackoverflow, How EXAMPLE are you?"

Any feasible solution to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how does 2130837661 map to EXAMPLE ?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Scary Wombat: EXAMPLE is the replacement

Comment: so if a numbr (which is preceded by ::) is in the arraylist then you will replace it with `EXAMPLE` ?

Comment: Yes, ::2130837661:: is a expression. whenever a integer comes between "::", check for that integer into arraylist values and if it contains, replaced it by new word.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question looks similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745154/how-to-replace-multiple-words-in-a-single-string-in-java

Comment: `Yes, ::2130837661:: is a expression. whenever a integer comes between "::", check for that integer into arraylist values and if it contains, replaced it by new word.`  - so which part are you stuck with?

Comment: There is already an answer. @Ambar Jain: Do you mind accepting or rejecting the answer?

Comment: @AmbarJain: Any updates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a Java String by the pipe symbol using split("|")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160/splitting-a-java-string-by-the-pipe-symbol-using-split)

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the `ArrayList` and (I assume you have a Map from these integers to Strings) use `String.replace()` to replace your integer with the respective replacement.

```
for(Integer i: arrayList)
{
  yourString.replace("::"+i+"::", replacement);
}
```

Comment: This has a very poor performance and does not work because Java returns a new string!

Comment: Just look at the OPs question. He has an `ArrayList` which consists of specific integers. If we were to simply use those integers hardcoded in the regex as your solution, what is the point of having this `ArrayList`? If Java returns a new `String`, simply assign it to the original `String` what is the issue?

Comment: I hope, he can interpret the regexp example and adjust it for his needs. As software dev you are supposed to think!

Comment: or you can use a good ol' Stringbuilder and then convert it to your needs