# Java: Replace only exactly matching URL

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to replace only exactly matching link given in String.
My code is as follows:

```
String originalString = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://example.com/\"><span style=\"font-size: 12px;\">ABC</span></a>"
            + "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://example.com/contact/\"><span style=\"font-size: 12px;\">Contact</span></a>";

String replacedString = originalString.replace("http://example.com/", "link1");
System.out.println("Replaced String:" + replacedString);


replacedString = "<a target="_blank" href="link1"><span style="font-size: 12px;">ABC</span></a><a target="_blank" href="link1contact/"><span style="font-size: 12px;">Contact</span></a>"

requiredString = "<a target="_blank" href="link1"><span style="font-size: 12px;">ABC</span></a><a target="_blank" href="link2"><span style="font-size: 12px;">Contact</span></a>"
```

I get Output as replacedString but required Output should be as requiredString.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to replace all occurrences of `http://example.com/` then use `replaceAll()`

Comment: if you want to replace the whole string you should use a regex after the string which goes until next backslash

Comment: Where do you replace it with `link2`?

Comment: @Imran replaceAll() is not working for required output

Comment: Your question was not clear earlier what to replace and what not to, hence `replaceAll` was suggested. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745154/how-to-replace-multiple-words-in-a-single-string-in-java) for solution.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer can you give example of regex??

Comment: @TwinkleSoni did you get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the URL with the quotes:

```
String replacedString = originalString.replace("\"http://example.com/\"", "\"link1\"");
replacedString = replacedString.replace("\"http://example.com/contact/\"", "\"link2\"");
```

Comment: The explanation is not clear ... and this will not gave the expected result. (but this is not really clear in the question)

Comment: Then this is only a half solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `http://example.com/contact/` contains `http://example.com/`.
Use this instead:

```
String replacedString = originalString.replace("http://example.com/contact/", "link2");
String replacedString2 = replacedString.replace("http://example.com/", "link1");
```

`replacedString2` is the required output

Comment: replaceAll()  also gives the same answer, it replaces both link.
But I want "http://example.com/contact/" to be replaced with link2

Comment: @TwinkleSoni Updated my answer, now it does it right

Comment: replaceAll takes a regexp as the first argument. replace is the way to go

Comment: @MauricePerry right. I accidentally put `replaceAll()`

Comment: Then, I would suggest to create a map somewhere. because this will end up with multiple replace call for link3, link4, link5, ... ;)

Comment: @AxelH there is no `link3,4,5`

Comment: There was no `link2` in his question (except in the needed result). Something tells me this will be a problem pretty soon ;)

Comment: @AxelH - that is true... I'm working on an implementation

Comment: @ItamarGreen it is working, but the order of links is not fixed. In my actual code I am extracting Links one by one and replacing them dynamically. So if example.com will come first then it will replace all strings.

Comment: @TwinkleSoni could you please give an example of a longer url? just to make it clearer how it should be

Comment: @ItamarGreen don't bother OP doesn't need to add requirements ! He asked to replace a String. Nothing more.

Comment: @AxelH - I don't think that's very nice to do that. OP needs help and I'm trying to give it (But if you think the answer is enough, by all means)

Comment: @TwinkleSoni as suggested earlier check here and implement one for yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745154/how-to-replace-multiple-words-in-a-single-string-in-java

Comment: @ItamarGreen, well OP doesn't care about your solution apparently ;) just want working codes...

Answer (score -3):

working regex is`http:\\/\\/example.com.*?(?=\\\\)` in java. it matches all occurences of `http://example.com` and until the next backslash