# Most efficient way to use replace multiple words in a string

Tags: java, replace

At the moment I'm doing

Example:

```
line.replaceAll(",","").replaceAll("cat","dog").replaceAll("football","rugby");
```

I think that it ugly. Not sure a better way to do this? Maybe loop through a hashmap?

EDIT:

By efficiency I mean better code style and flexibility

Comment: Is your question about runtime efficiency? Flexibility? Code style? Please clarify.

Comment: It may also be a question of correctness, for the replacements made during N passes may be not equivalent to performing replacements of N pairs during a single pass.

Comment: Updated question but looking for the code to be styled better and allow flexibility

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1326682/18511

Answer (score 23):

This functionality is already implemented in [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)'s `StringUtils` class.

```
StringUtils.replaceEach(String text, String[] searchList, String[] replacementList)
```

Comment: I believe it is not in standard library but rather in Apache Commons [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[]%29)

Comment: New version would be the [`StrSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/).

Comment: StrSubstitutor seems to have a different purpose than a standard replace.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)/[`appendTail()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) to build very flexible search-and-replace features.

The example in the JavaDoc looks like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cat");
Matcher m = p.matcher("one cat two cats in the yard");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "dog");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Now, inside that `while` loop you can decide yourself what the replacement text is and base that information on the actual content being matched.

For example you could use the pattern `(,|cat|football)` to match `,`, `cat` *or* `football` and decide on the actual replacement based on the actual match inside the loop.

You can make build even more flexible things this way, such as replacing all decimal numbers with hex numbers or similar operations.

It's not as *short* and *simple* as your code, but you can *build* short and simple methods with it.

Comment: What if you have hundreds of different words to check? The entire string would have to be scanned for each word, which is very inefficient.

Comment: @JackCole: no you wouldn't. Check the paragraph talking about the pattern with multiple words. You can still build a single pattern with any number of words.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You could follow up with a Map lookup of that word. I wonder how this performs in comparison to the above answer.

Comment: "For example you could use the pattern (,|cat|football) to match ,, cat or football and decide on the actual replacement based on the actual match inside the loop." Are you saying I could replace ',' with a '.' and 'cat' with 'dog' in one while loop? How does this look?

Comment: @Blaisem: exactly, that's what you can do. Inside the `while` loop simply inspect the return value of `m.group()` and the call àppendReplacement` with different second parameters based on what is returned.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from that the actual replace is internally converted to a `regex` I think that approach is fine. A non-regex implementation can be found in [StringUtils.replace(..)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) .

Looking at what alternatives there might be, you still need something to identify pairs of strings. This could look like:

```
MultiReplaceUtil.replaceAll{line, 
       {",", ""}, {"cat", "dog"}, {"football", "rugby"}};
```

or perhaps

```
MapReplaceUtil(String s, Map<String, String> replacementMap);
```

or even

```
ArrayReplaceUtil(String s, String[] target, String[] replacement);
```

neither of which seems more intuitive to me in terms of coding practice.

Answer (score 2):

For Scala lovers:

```
"cat".r.replaceAllIn("one cat two cats in the yard", m => "dog")
```

With `m` you can even parameterize your replacement.