# Remove apostrophe and white space from string

Tags: java

So I'm playing around string manipulation. I'm done replacing white space characters with hyphens. Now I want to combine replacing white spaces characters and removing apostrophe from string. How can I do this?

**This is what I've tried so far:**

```
    String str = "Please Don't Ask Me";
    String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\s+","-");

    System.out.println("New string is " + newStr);
```

**Output is:**

```
Please-Don't-Ask-Me
```

**But I want the output to be:**

```
Please-Dont-Ask-Me
```

But I can't get to work removing the apostrophe. Any ideas? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\s+","-").replaceAll("'", "");
```

The first `replaceAll` returns the String with all spaces replaced with `-`, then we perform on this another `replaceAll` to replace all `'` with nothing (Meaning, we are removing them).

Comment: This is OK unless you're dealing with really big strings... in that case an explicit `matcher.find() - matcher.appendReplacement()` loop would be needed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik [Indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658568/most-efficient-way-to-use-replace-multiple-words-in-a-string).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik can you give me some implementations of matcher.find()? I find the tutorials very confusing for a beginner

Comment: Have you clicked through Maroun's "Indeed" hyperlink above? I believe that answer covers it.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, use `replaceAll` again on the resulted String:

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\s+","-").replaceAll("'","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
String s = "This is a string that contain's a few incorrect apostrophe's. don't fail me now.'O stranger o'f t'h'e f'u't'u'r'e!";
        System.out.println(s);

        s = s.replace("\'", "");

        System.out.println("\n"+s);
```