# I need to remove ~50 color names from a vehicle description field in a large data file using Java/RegEx without arrays or loops

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a data integration tool that allows Java to help transform data. The problem is that I can't create arrays or use loops because they are not supported.

I have fields that have String values like:

```
04 Blue Honda Accord
12 Inferno Red Chevrolet Tahoe
10 Purple Ford Taurus
```

I just need to colors stripped out so they'd be:

```
04 Honda Accord
12 Chevrolet Tahoe
10 Ford Taurus
```

The only thing I can think of is creating a regular expression with the 49 color names, but I'm pretty bad at regex.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658568/most-efficient-way-to-use-replace-multiple-words-in-a-string.

Comment: Each field have only one word? And you need a string array as result?

Comment: @Elias Each field has multiple words. An example would be "12 Inferno Red Chevrolet Tahoe". I would need to remove the color (Inferno Red) so it would just say 12 Chevrolet Tahoe. It can't go in an array, I just need the words removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each field has only one value in form `digits colours description` ou can try something like

```
text = text.replaceFirst("(?i)(?<=\\d)\\s(red|green|blue)\\b","");
```

- `(?i)` will mare regex case insensitive so "red" will match "Red" or "RED" or "ReD" and so on
- `(?<=\\d)` will use [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) mechanism to check if before actual match will be digit
- `\\s` represents whitespace
- `(red|green|blue)` means red OR green OR blue
- `\\b` represents [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to check if color will not be part of next word in description like `greenhouses`

BTW if you have some colors that are part of some other colors like `gray` and `gray-red` then be sure to put the most specific before like `gray-red|gray`. It is important because regex will try to find match based on order from left to right, so if your text will contain `12 gray-red Mercedes` and you will use `replaceAll("gray|gray-red","")` you will see as result `12 -red Mercedes` because `gray` could be (and was) matched before `gray-red`.

Answer (score 3):

*UPDATED to eliminate the extra space in the output (changed `(.+)` to `[SPACE](.+)`).*

Assuming each car is on a separate line, this works:

```
^(\d+ )(?:Blue|Red|Purple|Inferno Red) (.+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/r3qWZzrBeSi_Fqjl)

Use

```
sNumColorCarLine.replaceAll(sTheRegex, "$1$2");
```

or

```
sNumColorCarLine.replaceFirst(sTheRegex, "$1$2");
```

to make the replacement. To be efficient though, especially if there are a lot of data lines, use the following, which avoids re-compiling the pattern (and re-creating the matcher) for every line:

```
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;

/**
   <P>{@code java RemoveColorFromCarLinesNoLoops}</P>
 **/
public class RemoveColorFromCarLinesNoLoops  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {

      //Add colors as necessary
      String sColorsNonCaptureOr = "(?:Blue|Red|Purple|Inferno Red)";
      String sRegex = "" +
         "^(\\d+ )" +            //one-or-more digits, then one space
         sColorsNonCaptureOr +   //color
         " (.+)$";               //Everything after the color (space uncaptured)

      String sRplcWith = "$1$2";

         //"": Unused search-string, so matcher can be reused.
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(sRegex).matcher("");

      String sColorRemoved1 = removeColorFromCarLine(m, "04 Blue Honda Accord", sRplcWith);
      String sColorRemoved2 = removeColorFromCarLine(m, "12 Inferno Red Chevrolet Tahoe", sRplcWith);
      String sColorRemoved3 = removeColorFromCarLine(m, "10 Purple Ford Taurus", sRplcWith);
   }
   private static final String removeColorFromCarLine(Matcher m_m, String s_origCarLine, String s_rplcWith)  {
      m_m.reset(s_origCarLine);
      if(!m_m.matches())  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Does not match: \"" + " + s_origCarLine + " + "\", pattern=[" + m_m.pattern() + "]");
      }

      //Since it matches(s), this is equivalent to "replace the entire line, as a whole"
      String s = m_m.replaceFirst(s_rplcWith);
      System.out.println(s_origCarLine + "  -->  " + s);
      return  s;
   }
}
```

Output

```
[C:\java_code\]java RemoveColorFromCarLinesNoLoops
04 Blue Honda Accord  -->  04 Honda Accord
12 Inferno Red Chevrolet Tahoe  -->  12 Chevrolet Tahoe
10 Purple Ford Taurus  -->  10 Ford Taurus
```

Answer (score 2):

This way you don't need to specify the color, and works in case of the color name has more than one word:

```
String field = "12 Inferno Red Chevrolet Tahoe";
field = field.replaceFirst("(\\d+).*(\\w+\\s\\w+)", "$1 $2");
System.out.println(field);
```

Prints:

```
12 Chevrolet Tahoe
```

The regex maintains only the number and the last two words of the input.

Comment: If the make and model are always exactly two words, it's a creative way to avoid having to maintain the color-list.

Comment: Indeed, if the color and the make/model don't have a constant number of words, it's impossible do build a regex like that.