# Multiple replace option for a string in java regex

Tags: java, android

How can I replace different match with different replacement regex 
if I have two match option separated by |, for each of the match I want to reference the string or substring that matches. 
if I have

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("man|woman|girls");
Matcher m = p.matcher("some string");
```

If the match is "man" I want to use a different replacement from when the match is "woman" or "girls".

I have looked through [Most efficient way to use replace multiple words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658568/most-efficient-way-to-use-replace-multiple-words-in-a-string) but dont understand how to reference the match itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider improving your pattern a little to add word-boundries to prevent it from patching only some part of words like `man` can be match for `mandatory`.

(BTW: Also in case you would want to replace words which have same start like `man` and `manual` you should place `manual` before `man` in regex, or `man` will consume `<man>ual` part which will prevent `ual` from being match. So correct order would be `manual|man`)

So your regex can look more like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(man|woman|girls)\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("some text about woman and few girls");
```

Next thing you can do is simply store pairs `originalValue -> replacement` inside some collection which will let you easily get replacement for value. Simplest way would be using Map

```
Map<String, String> replacementMap = new HashMap<>();
replacementMap.put("man", "foo");
replacementMap.put("woman", "bar");
replacementMap.put("girls", "baz");
```

Now your code can look like this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    String wordToReplace = m.group();
    //replace found word with with its replacement in map
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacementMap.get(wordToReplace));
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String replaced = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
str = 
   str.replace("woman", "REPLACEMENT1")
   .replace("man", "REPLACEMENT2")
   .replace("girls", "REPLACEMENT3");
```

Comment: okay thanks, but was hoping to use something of this nature           while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement();
}. found out its its does not use much of the cpu resources