# How to replace multiple substring of a string at one time?

Tags: java, android

I hope to replace two substring in the String s, so I write the following code. I think the efficiency is too low in my code when S is a huge string.

Can I replace multiple substring of a string at one time? or is there a better way to replace string?

**Added:**

I hope to find a way which can replace substring quickly!

```
   String s="This %ToolBar% is a %Content%";

   s=s.replace("%ToolBar%","Edit ToolBar");
   s=s.replace("%Content%","made by Paul");
```

Comment: You can always chain them like `s=s.replace("%ToolBar%","Edit ToolBar").replace("%Content%","made by Paul");` or see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658568/most-efficient-way-to-use-replace-multiple-words-in-a-string

Comment: how about regular expression?

Comment: I look at your code and I can understand it immediately, and would be able to maintain this code is 1 years time.  Why do you want to change that?

Comment: Thanks! To  Andrew Brooke:  When string is huge,  is your way s=s.replace("%ToolBar%","Edit ToolBar").replace("%Content%","made by Paul") more faster than mine?

Comment: @HelloCW No, it just uses method chaining for the same result. Each `replace()` call still searches the entire string.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to only perform one search of `s`, you can either do your own `indexOf()` loop, or use a regular expression replacement loop.

Here is an example of using a regular expression replacement loop, which uses the [`appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and [`appendTail()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail-java.lang.StringBuffer-) methods to build the result.

To eliminate the need for doing a string comparison to figure out which keyword was found, each keyword is made a capturing group, so existence of keyword can be quickly checked using [`start(int group)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start-int-).

```
String s = "This %ToolBar% is a %Content%";

StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("%(?:(ToolBar)|(Content))%").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.start(1) != -1)
        m.appendReplacement(buf, "Edit ToolBar");
    else if (m.start(2) != -1)
        m.appendReplacement(buf, "made by Paul");
}
m.appendTail(buf);
System.out.println(buf.toString()); // prints: This Edit ToolBar is a made by Paul
```

The above runs in Java 1.4 and later. In Java 9+, you can use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, or you can do it with a lambda expression using [`replaceAll​()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)):

```
String s = "This %ToolBar% is a %Content%";

String result = Pattern.compile("%(?:(ToolBar)|(Content))%").matcher(s)
        .replaceAll(m -> (m.start(1) != -1 ? "Edit ToolBar" : "made by Paul"));
System.out.println(result); // prints: This Edit ToolBar is a made by Paul
```

A more dynamic version can be seen in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407783/5221149).

Comment: Thanks! To Andreas: is your way very fastest way to replace substring?

Comment: `indexOf()` loop, if done correctly, may be slightly faster. This is simpler and still only searches your very long input once, which is the main concern.

Comment: Since Java 9 we can also use Matcher#replaceAll(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer). This allows us to skip explicit buffer and loop and allows us to write code like
`String result = Pattern
.compile("%(?:(ToolBar)|(Content))%")
.matcher(s)
.replaceAll(m -> (m.start(1) != -1) ? "Edit ToolBar": "made by Paul");`

Comment: @Pshemo Added to answer. Thanks.