# Insert Kotlins ${ } expression while splitting String() in order to add dynamic data after the split

Tags: java, string, kotlin, join, trim

Here is an example of a String:

```
val message = "Customer name is $name saved on $date"
```

I needed to find every instance of $variable within the string message and replace it with querySnapShot.get(variable) and that has been answered here [Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363893/replace-all-instances-of-certain-characters-within-a-string). querySnapShot here just contains data from within Firestore listener.

Here is the working Kotlin code:

```
val message = "Customer name is $name saved on $date"

    val arr = message.split(" ").toTypedArray()

    for (i in 0 until arr.size) {
        val s = arr[i]
        if (s.contains("$")) {
            arr[i] = "+ querySnapshot.get(" + "\"" + s.substring(1) + "\"" + ")"
        }
    }

    Log.d("Mate", java.lang.String.join(" ", *arr))
```

which prints:

```
customer name is querySnapShot.get("name") saved on querySnapshot.get("data)
```

literally as it is.

***QUESTION:*** 
How can I add Kotlin's expression ${} correctly while splitting and joining in order for it to treat querySnapshot.get("variable") as an expression that captures and returns dynamic data after joining? And not just a mere String.

Comment: I don't follow why you're not writing writing `arr[i] = querySnapshot.get(s.substring(1))`.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman , your comment is literally what i've been looking for, thank you so much for the brain teaser. Post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I would suggest that if string templating is useful, then _use_ Kotlin or Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
arr[i] = querySnapshot.get(s.substring(1))
```

The solution isn't to try to use Kotlin string templating, it's to stop putting your own code in strings when you want to run it instead!