# Elegant string replace in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string where I have to replace some content:

```
"...content... <a href='document/link/B1'>foo</a> ...content... <a href='document/link/B2'>bar</a> ..."
```

I'm looking for a clean way to obtain something like this:

```
"...content... <a href='document/link/23'>foo</a> ...content... <a href='document/link/24'>bar</a> ..."
```

Where '23' and '24' in the links are results of some processing that I did. So first I should be able to select the links, get their url (more specific: I need the B1 and B2) and then I have to perform some actions with e.g. B1 which results in '23' which I then have to insert back again in the string.

Is there a nice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's bad idea to use regex to parse HTML/XML. But for some sporadical use (run just once) and if you are sure about the structure of your HTML and don't require much robustness, something like this (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326682/java-replacing-multiple-different-substring-in-a-string-at-once-or-in-the-most)) could do the trick:

```
   String original = "..content... <a href='document/link/B1'>foo</a> ...content... <a href='document/link/B2'>bar</a> ...";
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   // tweak the following
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<a href='document/link/)([^']*)('>)");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(original);
   while(matcher.find()) {
      String oldlinkPart = matcher.group(2);
      String newlinkPart = buildNewLinkPart(oldLinkPart); // here you do your look-up
      matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(1) + newlinkPart + matcher.group(3));
   }
   matcher.appendTail(sb);
   String modified = sb.toString();
```

You can tweak the regex pattern to be slightly more general (more spaces, tabs, additional atttributes inside the A tag, case sensitivity, doble quotes), but when you start to pretend to be *totally* general, so that your code works with any well formed HTML, then you're screwed: try instead with a XML/DOM parser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had to make a small adjustment: had to change the 2nd group to `([A-Z][0-9]*)` to make it work.