# How would i replace multiple items with a single item depending on what is being replaced

Tags: java

I am trying to replace certain characters with other certain characters using one `.replace()`

eg.
I would like to replace

`\u0026` with `&`

and

`\u0027` with `'`

depending on which is needed to be replaced.

Comment: No. You will need multiple `replace` calls.

Comment: But why you can't cal .replace() two times with different inputs? Or can you extend your question with some code and more precise context?

Comment: To those asking why not call `.replace()` twice: Imagine you are replacing a string that contains 1 billion characters. You really don't want to call `replace()` twice as that would create an intermediate 2-gigabyte object when it can be avoided by coding it differently.

Comment: See [Alternative to successive String.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735276/alternative-to-successive-string-replace)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have multiple `.replace` calls because you want to replace specific items with other specific items

If you wanted to replace any instance of `\u0027` or `\u0026` with just one character then you could use a single replace.

However, to achieve what you want, then you need something like this:

```
str.replace("\u0027","'").replace("\u0026","&")
```

Comment: Better approach would be `return str.replace("\u0027","'").replace("\u0026","&")`. No need to use `contains`.