# Java multiple regex on string

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to apply multiple regex on a string. I'm not able to get a good understanding on something of this matter.

I have multiple strings which would under go this replacement:

```
String csvFile = "/Users/john/Documents/chartFolder/chart_test_1.csv"
String chartTitle = csvFile.replaceAll("_", " ");
chartTitle = chartTitle.replaceAll(".*/", "");
chartTitle = chartTitle.replaceAll("\\..*", "");
```

I'd like the output to be -

```
chart test 1
```

which I achieve, but I feel is not good coding due to the multiple lines of coding.

If someone could please explain if it can be done in 1 line and how they come up with the solution, without just posting the solution that would be great.

Comment: you can group the 2nd and 3rd replacement, as you're replacing for the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Replacing multiple different substring in a string at once (or in the most efficient way)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326682/java-replacing-multiple-different-substring-in-a-string-at-once-or-in-the-most)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with multiple lines of code. Clean, easy to read code is more maintainable than dense 'clever' (oh look what I did in one line) code.

Comment: For the 2nd replacement I'm taking all characters out before the / so the string becomes "chart_test_1.csv" and for the 3rd replacement I'm deleting all characters after the "."

Answer (score 1):

You can concatinate all the replace Statements:

```
String chartTitle = csvFile.replaceAll("_", " ").replaceAll(".*/", "").replaceAll("\\..*", "");
```

Comment: concatenate*  (sorry I tried so hard not to post, but couldn't help myself)

Comment: Is it possible to make the .replaceAll(".*/", "").replaceAll("\\..*", "") into 1 .replaceAll?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one replace, like this:

```
String chartTitle = csvFile.replaceAll(".*/|_|\\..*", " ").trim();
```

This uses an *alternation" to match all three targets, then replace them all with a space, which leaves a space at either end, which are then removed using `trim()`.

The main problem with your idea, for which there is no work around, is that `replaceAll()`'s replacement term can't vary depending on the match.

You may also be interested to know that `replace()` still replaces all occurrences, it just uses a plain text pattern (not a regex), so you could code

```
str.replace("_",  " ")
```

with equal effect

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself some `.replaceAll` by building a better regular expression (which targets several substrings to replace), but only if the replacement String remains the same.

In your example:

```
chartTitle = chartTitle.replaceAll(".*/", "");
chartTitle = chartTitle.replaceAll("\\..*", "");
```

Can be grouped as you replace  matches with the same substring (here : ""). You can use the "or" operator to build a "grouped" regular expression.

Otherwise, you have to call this function several times.