# Replace words in java using hashmap and properties file

Tags: java, replace, hashmap, tokenize

how can I replace words using map that populate the value in properties file?

I have this code to load the properties file:

```
Properties propertiesSlang = new Properties();
FileInputStream fileReadSlang = new FileInputStream(slang);
propertiesSlang.load(fileReadSlang);
System.out.println(propertiesSlang);
Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>((Map)propertiesSlang);
```

I have many slang tokens that I have to replace, how can I replace the slang tokens?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Question is not clear.

Comment: are you trying to do something like this: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076568/learn-java/localize-this-.html ? (localization)

Comment: See a generalized solution to replace words in a string http://stackoverflow.com/a/1326962/1737819 .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace words in an array, use a simple iteration:

```
String[] words;
//...
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i ++) {
    String word = words[i];
    String rep = replacements.get(word);
    if (rep != null) {
        words[i] = rep;
    }
}
```