# java efficient way to call String replace multiple times

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

I need to go something like:

```
public String func (String str){
    str = str.replace("aaa","bbb");
    str = str.replace("ccc","ddd");
    str = str.replace("eee","fff");
    return str;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do so? i guess that every replace function complexity is O(n), so three times calling replace will be O(3n).
I am sure it is possible to be implemented in O(n), is there a simple way to do so with JAVA ??

(and an elegant way to do so with JAVA 8 in case the replacement input comes from a function like str.replace("aaa", getFirstReplacement()) ).

Comment: Note that `replace` returns a new String containing the results of the replacement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326682/java-replacing-multiple-different-substring-in-a-string-at-once-or-in-the-most may help

Comment: In this case, you can replace the entire method body with `return str;`, that will do the same.

Comment: You could iterate over the string looking for occurrences strings you'd like to replace, then continually append to a string builder rather than creating new strings.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios Delimanolis i edited