# Replacing values inside curly brackets with parameters

Tags: java, parsing, parameters

Let's say i have a string like this: `"/c1/client/{clientId}/field/{fieldId}/version/{versionId}/file/{filename}"`

I want to replace all values inside curly brackets with the actual values, so the link would look like this:

```
"c1/client/Tudor/field/search/version/1/file/hello.txt".
```

How can i do that in a way that does not limit the number of parameters used? Because i have some requests with 4 parameters (like this one) and others with only one parameter, or none. What is the best way to do this?

Edit: I would need something like: Search string for any values between {}. If string contains {value}, take all {values} and replace with parameter.

Comment: you could go with a `Map<String, String> parameterValueMap` in order to store the key <-> value relation you´d need and simply call a replace all for each `{keyInTheMap}` and could replace it with the repctive value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Replacing multiple different substring in a string at once (or in the most efficient way)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326682/java-replacing-multiple-different-substring-in-a-string-at-once-or-in-the-most)

Comment: 1. is your clientid always going to be a value "Tudor"?
2. Or is the first {parameter} always "Tudor"?

Comment: not necessarily. may have multiple values, but i can deal with that in another way. What i need is a way to replace {clientId} with Tudor, regardless of how many {parameters} i have.

Answer (score 1):

In case of String:

```
var u = "/c1/client/{clientId}/field/{fieldId}/version/{versionId}/file/{filename}";
u.replace(/\{clientId\}/, "Tudor").replace(/\{fieldId\}/, "search").replace(/\{versionId\}/, 1).replace(/\{filename}/, "hello.txt");
```

Comment: Yes but in another request, it will not be {clientId}, will be {createClient} for example... i am looking for a method that takes everything that is inside curly brackets and replace them with the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse @pathParameters and redirect to the address you create with spring @controller. If these are request as you wrote that is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
String str = "/c1/client/{clientId}/field/{fieldId}/version/{versionId}/file/{filename}";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("clientId", "Tudor");
map.put("fieldId", "search");
map.put("versionId", "1");
map.put("filename", "hello.txt");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
str = str.replace("{" + entry.getKey() + "}", entry.getValue());
}
String newStr = str.substring(1);
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: and what happens if i only have three parameters, with other names?

Comment: @Tudor You know the mapping for your all parameters?

Comment: Yes, i will have a value for each parameter there. the thing is, i want something to search the string for values between curly brackets. If found, then replace {parameter} with his value.

Comment: @Tudor So you have to only map those parameters?

Comment: I have to map parameters inside curly brackets. So i won;t have only those parameters, i need something like: search for {parameter}, if it exists replace {parameter} with value.

Comment: @Tudor Have you tried this? By using `str.replace("{" + entry.getKey() + "}", entry.getValue());` your `{parameter}` replace with value that you defined in your mapping.

Comment: Ok, then how do i extract from the initial string the clientId, fieldId, versionId and filename that i put in the hashmap? because i have 200 requests to test, and i don;t want to manually extract those values for every request.

Comment: @Tudor You must have to map your all values and for this you can use `HashMap`. This is what I have done. Is this not your requirement?

Comment: @Tudor Is this helpful for you?

Comment: No, i just told you. I do not need to map all values. I need something that searches for any word that starts with { and ends with }, and then do the replacement.

Comment: @Tudor How can they do replacement? You have to map those word Right?

Comment: @Tudor I don't know what you talking about the request. Can you show your full code? What you trying to do?