# Regex in Java - parsing a string array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, java-8

I have a string array like this:

```
    String tweetString = ExudeData.getInstance().filterStoppingsKeepDuplicates(tweets.text);
    // get array of words and split
    String[] wordArray = tweetString.split(" ");
```

After I split the array, I print the following:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordArray));
```

And the output I get is:

```
[new, single, fallin, dropping, days, artwork, hueshq, production, iseedaviddrums, amp, bigearl7, mix, reallygoldsmith, https, , , t, co, dk5xl4cicm, https, , , t, co, rvqkum0dk7]
```

What I want is to remove all the instances of commas, https, and single letters like 't' (after using `split` method above). So I want to end up with this:

```
[new, single, fallin, dropping, days, artwork, hueshq, production, iseedaviddrums, amp, bigearl7, mix, reallygoldsmith, co, dk5xl4cicm, https, co, rvqkum0dk7]
```

I've tried doing replaceAll like this:

```
String sanitizedString = wordArray.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll(",+", ",");
```

But that just gave me the same initial output with no changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Easier to answer if you provide the original input. Note that `split` itself takes a regex. You might want to start with that.

Comment: @Mena - yes I want to parse out the strings I mentioned above after I used the split method if you read my actual question

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have actual commas in your output array, only empty strings.

Comment: Also, `wordArray` is an array, so you can't possibly have used `replaceAll` on it - it wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: oh good point, thanks for pointing those out! @RealSkeptic

Comment: Use this to first replace/remove all multiple matching words with "" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326682/java-replacing-multiple-different-substring-in-a-string-at-once-or-in-the-most and then split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(tweetString.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

> What I want is to remove all the instances of commas, https, and single letters like 't'

In this case you can make multiple filters like @Andronicus do or with matches and some regex like so :

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(tweetString.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(s -> !s.matches("https|.|\\s+"))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I'm using Java 11

Comment: @Hana what work in Java 8 work in Java 11 except depricated, so my code work in both of them

Comment: THANK YOU! This one worked for me :) the second result you posted was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
String[] filtered = Arrays
    .stream(tweetString.split("[ ,]"))
    .filter(str -> str.length() > 1)
    .filter(str -> !str.equals("http"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment here is quick solution. (Enhance the regex with all your keywords)

```
 private static void replaceFromRegex(final String text ) {
    String result = text.replaceAll("https($|\\s)| (?<!\\S)[^ ](?!\\S)","");
      System.out.println(result);
  }
```

and then test

```
  public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
      replaceFromRegex("new single fallin dropping, , https");
     }
```

Note: This is just sample and you will have to enhance regex to consider starting word (e.g string starting with https and then space, etc)