# Replace a map of values in string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, replace

Let's say I have a `String text = "abc"` and I want to replace a map of values, eg:

```
a->b
b->c
c->a
```

How would you go for it?

Because obviously:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(el -> text = text.replaceAll(el.getKey(), el.getValue()))
```

won't work, since the second replacement will overwrite also the first replacement (and at the end you won't get `bca`)

So how would you avoid this "replacement of the previous replacement"?

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326682/java-replacing-multiple-different-substring-in-a-string-at-once-or-in-the-most) but I hope in a more concise and naive solution (and hopefully without the use of Apache external packages)

**By the way** the string can be also more than one character

Comment: a, b, c are strings or chars?

Comment: (and at the end you won't get cba)  >> Did you mean `bca`  for `abc`?

Comment: What’s the type of the map? `Map<Character, Character>` or `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: hi all, sorry for the delay, "map of strings", so `Map<String, String>`

Comment: If the map is string to string, the "replace" operations are order dependant. Is the map a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html)? If not, how to order determined?

Comment: @Bohemian good point... the order it's not relevant for the sake of the example (but yes, it's order dependent).. you might think like a `List<Pair<String, String>>`, so there order is the position of the pair in the list

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution with java streams.

```java
String text = "abc";
Map<String, String> replaceMap = new HashMap<>();
replaceMap.put("a", "b");
replaceMap.put("b", "c");
replaceMap.put("c", "a");

System.out.println("Text = " + text);

text = Arrays.stream(text.split("")).map(x -> {
    String replacement = replaceMap.get(x);
    if (replacement != null) {
        return x.replace(x, replacement);
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}).collect(Collectors.joining(""));

System.out.println("Processed Text = " + text);
```

Output

```
Text = abc
Processed Text = bca
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would handle cases where the string to replace is longer than one character (because it uses `text.split("")`).

Comment: Yes. The PO did not mention that he wanted to map words. I crafted this answer to go with the given requirement.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but this works only for the example, but a string can be also longer than one character

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I'd normal handle with regex replacement. The code for that in Java is a bit verbose, but this should work:

```
String text = "abc";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "b");
map.put("b", "c");
map.put("c", "a");

String regex = map.keySet()
                  .stream()
                  .map(s -> Pattern.quote(s))
                  .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));

String output = Pattern.compile(regex)
                       .matcher(text)
                       .replaceAll((m) -> {
                           String s = m.group();
                           String r = map.get(s);
                           return r != null ? r : s;
                       });
System.out.println(output); 
// bca
```

It's relatively straightforward, if a little verbose because Java. First, create a regex expression that will accept any of the keys in the map (using `Pattern.quote()` to sanitize them), and then use lambda replacement to pluck the appropriate replacement from the map whenever an instance is found.

The performance-intensive part is just compiling the regex in the first place; the replacement itself should make only one pass through the string.

Should be compatible with Java 1.9+

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 onwards, there is a method called [`chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--) that returns an IntStream from which you can get a character corresponding to integer represented by the character and map it using your map.

If your map is String to String map then you could use:

```
text = text.chars().mapToObj(el -> map.get(String.valueOf((char)el))).
                                                 collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

if your map is Character to Character then just remove String.valueOf()

```
text = text.chars().mapToObj(el -> map.get((char)el)).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer and for your time, but this works only for the example, but a string can be also longer than one character