# spring boot security- adding custom role names

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am following a spring boot JPA authentication security tutorial. I have set up authentication for USERS and ADMINS.

however in MySQL database i have custom roles such as 'principal' and 'teacher' and 'student'

How can I add these custom roles to my authentication.

I am assuming I need to do this in the UserDetails class. here is my code so far

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.active = user.isActive();
        this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getTheType().split(","))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the tutorial/lesson, it is ok when you (try to) rename/refactor:

- the roles (useres, admins ... roles or authorities? tomayto, tomahto (just prepend/cutoff a `ROLE_`;)
- the db columns.

But the least intrusive and quite efficient (for only 2 roles/few combinations) approach would be like:

```
// adjust to requirements:
static final String REGEX_USERS = "student"; // exact match
static final String REGEX_ADMINS = "(teacher|principal)"; // group OR match
static final String AUTH_ADMINS = "ADMINS";
static final String AUTH_USERS = "USERS";
```

...and then:

```
this.authorities = Arrays.stream(
         user
         .getTheType()
         .replaceAll(REGEX_USERS, USERS)
         .replaceAll(REGEX_ADMINS, ADMINS)
         .split(",")
       )
       .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A standalone test:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

class TestO {

  static final String REGEX_USERS = "student";
  static final String REGEX_ADMINS = "(teacher|principal)";

  static final String AUTH_ADMINS = "ADMINS";
  static final String AUTH_USERS = "USERS";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String testData1 = "student";
    String testData2 = "teacher,principal";
    List<GrantedAuthority> result1 = Arrays.stream(testData1
        .replaceAll(REGEX_USERS, AUTH_USERS)
        .replaceAll(REGEX_ADMINS, AUTH_ADMINS)
        .split(","))
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.format("%s%n", result1);
    List<GrantedAuthority> result2 = Arrays.stream(testData2
        .replaceAll(REGEX_USERS, AUTH_USERS)
        .replaceAll(REGEX_ADMINS, AUTH_ADMINS)
        .split(","))
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.format("%s%n", result2);

  }
}
```

Prints:

```
[USERS]
[ADMINS, ADMINS]
```

---

If my assumptions(!) about role-mappings were correct:

- all `student` are `USERS`
- all `teacher` are `ADMINS`
- there is only 1 (few) `principal` ..and also `ADMIN` (and also `teacher` ?? ...please! school systems vary widely...;-)
- `principal` is the only one who has a comma in his (authority) list!?
- (no `student` is `teacher`!?)

Then probably (and in any "granted authority specific" case):

```
private java.util.Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
```

...then also:

```
Collectors.toSet() // + refacotrings
```

is preferrable! ([What is the difference between Set and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1035008/592355) !;)

So:

```
Set<GrantedAuthority> result2 = Arrays.stream(testData2
        .replaceAll(REGEX_USERS, "USERS")
        .replaceAll(REGEX_ADMINS, "ADMINS")
        .split(","))
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.format("%s%n", result2);
```

Prints:

```
...
[ADMINS]
```

See also (reg. *efficient* string replacement):

[Java Replacing multiple different substring in a string at once (or in the most efficient way)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1326682/592355)

Comment: thank you, and if I wanted to add an additional user how can I go about doing that? so I have three custom users if that makes snese

Comment: welcome! :-) for an additional user: we would add one more regexp and `replaceAll`

Comment: if we know well/have good assumptions about the data, we can get more efficiency out of it! (eg. when you know it is *always* `teacher, principal` and *never* `principal,teacher`,  ..or that `student` never has comma ...things like that :)..then we wouldn't even split (+stream+collect), but just replace! ;)

Comment: ..or "whenever there is a comma it is an admin"! :):) ..and test-test-test! :)